# Advice on c++ class interface design: how would you name these two methods to make them obvious?

Tags: c++, class, methods, naming-conventions, conventions

I have a very simple concrete class that represents a point in 2D space, it has two methods to shift the point given a radius and an angle: one modifies the object itself, the other creates another object leaving the first one unchanged:

```
template<class T =double> class cls_2DPoint
{
    ...
    cls_2DPoint<T>& polar_move(const T r, const double a) noexcept
       {
        x+=r*std::cos(a); y+=r*std::sin(a); return *this;
       }
    cls_2DPoint<T> polar_moved(const T r, const double a) const noexcept
       {
        return cls_2DPoint<T>(x+r*std::cos(a), y+r*std::sin(a));
       }
    ...
    T x,y;
};
```

This is actually code that I'm using! While reviewing it I realized that this was a reckless design: not obvious, error prone, making the user code less readable.
Since I'm struggling to find a convincing alternative, I thought to ask advice here: are there general conventions/guidelines for naming modifying and non-modifying methods? Are there best practices that could help me here to improve the design?

Comment: It will be easier if you add another class - `cls_2DVector`. Then you can define operator methods using the two types that will feel natural.

Comment: @r-sahu I'm wondering, something like this? `cls_2DPoint<> p(1,1); cls_2DVector<> vshift; vshift.set_polar_coords(2, 3.14); p+=vshift;` I'm not sure about the introduction of another class, wouldn't be 2DPoint and 2DVector essentially the same thing?

Comment: The idea would be to distinguish between a point and a displacement. A point is a single location, a displacement is the difference between two locations. This also maybe makes it a little clearer that you're converting the polar coordinates to rectangular displacement then applying it to the point. If `polar_move` were defined as "convert the LHS to polar coordinates, change its radius by `r` and its angle by `a`", it would yield different results than what you've written.

Comment: @nathan-pierson Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions.

### Use `namespace` instead of prefix for class name

```
namespace cls2D
{
   class Point { ... };
}
```

### Add class `Vector`

```
namespace cls2D
{
   class Point { ... };
   class Vector { ... };
}
```

### Define operator methods

Define operator methods that work with the two object types. Prefer non-member functions if you can get away with it.

```
namespace cls2D
{
   class Vector;

   class Point
   { 
      public:

         Point& operator+=(Vector v);
         Point& operator-=(Vector v);

      private:
         double x = 0;
         double y = 0;
      
   };

   class Vector
   {
      public:

         Vector& operator+=(Vector v);
         Vector& operator-=(Vector v);

      private:
         double x = 0;
         double y = 0;
   };

   Point from_polar(double r, double th);
   Point from_vector(Vector v);
   Vector from_point(Point p);

   Point operator+(Point p, Vector v);
   Point operator+(Vector v, Point p);
   Vector operator+(Vector v1, Vector v2);

   Vector operator-(Point p1, Point p2);
   Vector operator-(Vector v1, Vector v2);

}
```

Please note that `Point` and `Vector` have the same member data. Hence, it's tempting to use just one class to represent both. However, I think of them as two different abstractions and deserve to be different classes.

I removed the `template` part in my answer to make illustration of the idea simpler.

I assume you know how to add the necessary costructors to the classes.

Comment: So the one-to-one correspondence between points and vectors doesn't mean that a point is a vector, I understand. This would introduce quite big changes, I need to think about this.

Answer (score 1):

I would name them like this:

```
template<class T =double> class cls_2DPoint
{
    ...

    cls_2DPoint<T>& polarMovePoint(const T r, const double a) noexcept
       {
        x+=r*std::cos(a); y+=r*std::sin(a); return *this;
       }

    cls_2DPoint<T> polarMovePointClone(const T r, const double a) const noexcept
       {
        return cls_2DPoint<T>(x+r*std::cos(a), y+r*std::sin(a));
       }
    ...
    T x,y;
};
```

This type of labeling would let me know which function moves the point itself and which function creates a clone of the point and than moves that.

Comment: Linear and simple, better than mine for sure because here the intent is very clear. This points me out the presence of two verbs in the function name, maybe that method does too many things at once.